# Animate Pseudo CSS elements - any framework?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I was working on creating a bar chart, which had pseudo css elements (::before, ::after).

While I got it to a point where the bars look nice, I can't find a good way to animate the height changes. When I use the animate function, the pseudo elements disappear, and only appear when the animation completes. Anyone else has an idea on how to achieve this? Is there any other animation framework that will render the pseudo elements as well?

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyGamW

HTML

```
<ul><li><div class="fill bar1">100%</div></li></ul>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  background:#cdcdcf;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-top:40px;
}
li{
float:left;
height:800px;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.fill {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  top: 161px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
  left: 70px;
  border: none;
  font: normal normal bold 26px/normal Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-align: left;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,43,43,1) 0, rgba(209,31,31,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,43,43,1) 0, rgba(209,31,31,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,43,43,1) 0, rgba(209,31,31,1) 100%);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: auto auto;
  background-size: auto auto;
  -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1)  skewY(-3deg);
  transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1)  skewY(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 11px 18px -5px #841313 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 11px 18px -5px #841313 inset;
}

.fill::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  font: normal normal normal 16px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.901961);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-180deg, #c62121 0, rgba(132,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #c62121 0, rgba(132,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #c62121 0, rgba(132,19,19,1) 100%);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: auto auto;
  background-size: auto auto;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateX(-44px) skewY(20deg);
  transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateX(-44px) skewY(20deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 11px 18px -5px #841313 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 11px 18px -5px #841313 inset;
}

.fill::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.1px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  font: normal normal normal 16px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.901961);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: rgba(132,19,19,1);
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateX(-50%) translateY(-91%) skewX(70.5deg);
  transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) scaleZ(1) translateX(-50%) translateY(-91%) skewX(70.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        doAnimation();
    },4000);
    doAnimation();
});
function doAnimation() {
  $('.fill').animate({ "height": "150px", "top": "311px"}, 1000);
  $('.fill').delay(1000).animate({ "height": "300px", "top": "161px"}, 1000);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` rather than animating a whole bunch of properties - you avoid forgetting to reset a property as you go back and forth between animation states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure how **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**'s [`TweenMax`](http://greensock.com/tweenmax) differs from **jQuery**'s `.animate()` method in this particular case but replacing your animation with `TweenMax` does solve your problem.

**JavaScript:**

```
TweenMax.to('.fill', 1, {
  height: 150,
  top: 311,
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true,
  ease: Expo.easeInOut
});
```

As a side note, I would strongly recommend using **GSAP** for all your JS animation needs. Look into the **[documentation](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/)** for available methods and properties.

**[Here](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/qOwGgQ)** is your forked pen.

Hope this helps.